# Which type of database in orientdb is similar to neo4j's graph db

Tags: graph, neo4j, orientdb

I am new to orientdb , I read that even document type of orientdb has relationships , so I would like to know which type to select , either `graph` or `document` to resemble neo4j graph db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Graph is similar to Neo4j. Furthermore if you use [TinkerPop Blueprints API](http://blueprints.tinkerpop.com/) you can switch from Neo4J to OrientDB (and viceversa) in a flash.